# Handle Process Delegate of PXProcessingJoin

Tags: acumatica

I have created a delegate to handle the Process button. My data view is a PXProcessingJoin.

I would like that in my Delegate, I also access the joined tables and not the main DAC only. It seems that the Delegate will be passed the main DAC and not the joined table.

I can of course go to the database to retrieve the joined tables but I would like to avoid this overhead. I could also consider to use a PxProjection but I would like to avoid the plumbing code of the PxProjection where you need to repeat all Bql classes and properties.

Is there a what to have access to the joined tables in the Process Delegate directly?

Comment: Good question. I have not seen any way of doing this that i am aware of, but not looked in much detail. Would be nice to know if there is a way to do that, otherwise I think PXProjection is going to be what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After speaking to Acumatica, I was informed that this was by design due to performance optimizations. They confirmed that my suggestion of using a PXProjection would be a suitable workaround.